# Android permission denied for /dev directory

Tags: android, linux, adb, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I need to be able to read/write file "/dev/block/mmcblk0" from Android application code. But it is not read/write. What to do in this case? I use Jelly Bean.

Comment: You want to read/write a block device?  Are you sure?

Comment: You mean, without rooting device, I cannot run application that reads files from this directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be loged as root user (root the device).

@user1379574:

No, you can't.

That is a system directory, not yours, you usually don't have nothing to do here...

And if you need to do something here you must have permissions to do it (been root).